# Execute psql query in bash

Tags: bash, psql

I have a problem with executing a psql-query in a bash script.
Below is my code.

```
run_sql(){
  sql_sel="$1;";#sql select
  table=$2;#table name
  for i in "${!GP_SERVER_NAMES[@]}"
  do
  logmsg "Executing [$sql_sel] on "${GP_SERVER_NAMES[$i]}": " $loglvl;
result_host[$i]=`${PSQL_HOST[$i]}${sql_sel}`;
#result_host[$i]=cleanresult "`$(${PSQL_HOST[$i]} "$tx_fix $sql_sel" 2>&1`");
  if [[ `checkresult "${result_host[$i]}"` != 'true' ]]; then
     logmsg "Error occured during sql select: Result for "${GP_SERVER_NAMES[$i]}"     '${table}': ${result_host[$i]};" '1' '1';
         raise_alarm "${GP_SYNC_SQL_ERR}" "${i}" "${table}" "${result_host}";
  fi
  logmsg "Result for" ${GP_SERVER_NAMES[$i]} " '${table}': ${result_host[$i]}";
  done

final_result='true';

 for i in "${!result_host[@]}"
 do
 if [[ `checkresult "${result_host[$i]}"` = 'true' ]]; then
  final_result='false';
```

I am trying to executing the query on many different servers, with the following command
result_host[$i]=`${PSQL_HOST[$i]}${sql_sel}`;
The above variables have the following meaning:
1. result_host[$i] : is an array that holds the i-th result of the sql query.
2. PSQL_HOST[$i] : is the command line psql-statement, including the IP address which is of the form 
 psql -t -q -h -U password -d database -c
3. $sql_sel : is the sql_statement

When I run the script, I get the following output.

scriptname.sh: line 168: SELECT: command not found
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: SELECT
              ^

Why is that? Any help, comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to actually show the `psql` invocation in that script. That's be kind of handy. In general I strongly recommend doing this sort of thing with a language that has a real PostgreSQL database binding - e.g. Python with psycopg2, or Perl with DBD::Pg. Anyway, I'm sure this will be a quoting problem, but with only part of the relevant code I can't easily say more than that.

Comment: The psql invocation is done via the backtick operator, no?
result_host[$i]=\`${PSQL_HOST[$i]}${sql_sel}\`;

Comment: Why did you comment this line... #result_host[$i]=cleanresult "`$(${PSQL_HOST[$i]} "$tx_fix $sql_sel" 2>&1`"); you are NOT using the backquote character \`, \` and $( .. ) bracket placement correctly. Seems like the if you use this, it might work for you: result_host[$i]=cleanresult $(${PSQL_HOST[$i]} "$tx_fix $sql_sel" 2>&1`);  -OR result_host[$i]=cleanresult "$(${PSQL_HOST[$i]} "$tx_fix $sql_sel" 2>&1`)";   -OR result_host[$i]="$(cleanresult \`${PSQL_HOST[$i]} "$tx_fix $sql_sel" 2>&1\`)";  ### Again, run your script with "bash -x yourscript" and see what debug info comes.